# Quick-release for boat battery terminal loops

Tags: boats

I have a [D18S/T3](https://ajcbattery.com/product/ajc-12v-18ah/) battery that I want to use to power the lights of an aluminum boat.

[image]

I don't want to leave the battery in the boat when I'm not using it. I figure the elements would damage the battery over time. So I want to easily remove the battery after each use and store it elsewhere.

So far, I've been using nuts and bolts to attach the wiring [ring connectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOTrc.png) to the battery. But unthreading the bolt each time to disconnect the battery is tedious.

Is there such a thing as a quick-release mechanism for this style of battery terminal? Something more secure than flimsy [alligator clips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY5sU.png), possibly similar to a [bicycle quick-release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi9w4.png) mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are called T3 terminals (yup, in the name - perhaps the battery comes in different terminal options?). I have not found anything that looks like a quick-disconnect option for those terminals though.

Instead of messing with the battery terminals, I would use a connector rated for the maximum current you expect to use. My personal favorite would be an Anderson Powerpole. They come in different current capacities, all rated at 600V ac or dc. Various sizes are available, and with up to a 350A capacity you will find one that works. Once can add on environmental protection to reduce water ingress, and various positive-locking options. I use them for ham radio equipment (quite common in that field), and for connectors to my auxiliary battery system on my truck (one 100A line to the back of the truck, and 2 30A color-code-keyed lines to my roof-top tent).

I would also strongly (very strongly!) recommend adding an inline fuse on the battery side, rated to handle your expected normal current draw while protecting whichever connector you choose from exceeding its rated capacity. Also use appropriate rubber boots over the T3 terminals to insulate them from accidental contact.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea where I can get the T3 rubber boots? Do they have a specific name?

Comment: I've never looked for those in particular, but someplace that sells those batteries likely has kit for them as well.